What issues are there with my perspective on truth?
There are multiple definitions on how to describe what is "true", and what is not, but the problem is how we isolate a definition that helps us understand what the “truth” is as objectively as possible. Truth’s textbook definition is “that which is true or in accordance with fact or reality”. This barely grasps the main fundamentals of understanding about truth since the definition quite literally says that which is true. It is my belief that truth can be summed up as all ideas which can be backed up by evidence and have a solid reasoning connecting the evidence to the idea. But I have seen ideas where it states that everything is true until proven false, or that nothing is true; it's just that is hasn't been proven false yet.
My question to sum it up is that why can't the truth be described as something with an idea that can be backed up by solid evidence and reasoning. What situations can cause this idea to fall apart?

There are many theories of truth. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth#Major_theories

There may be truths that cannot be backed up by solid evidence and reasoning simply because they are beyond our perception and/or comprehension, those are called verification-transcendent truths. And even something backed up by solid evidence and reasoning can turn out to be false, as some scientific theories did in the past. So evidence and reasoning cannot define truth, they can only be (fallible) guides to it.

"the problem is how we isolate a definition that helps us understand what the “truth” is as objectively as possible." -- whose problem is that? Certainly it is not a problem arising naturally from there being multiple definitions of "true".  This is not a matter of your beliefs about what is true.  From a philosophical perspective, it is not the case that one definition of truth is inherently better than another, or that there is a "true truth" to be found. Some definitions are more useful than others in certain contexts, but that does not make them more right.

So, if I say "I was thinking about my house a few seconds ago", I am definitionally not speaking the truth because I can hardly present evidence for my statement nor can I provide "solid reasoning"? I believe you are mistaking verifiability with truth - many things are true but difficult to verify (and some things we believe we have verified later turn out to be false).

Well, suppose a dinosaur tripped and broke its ankle 200 million years ago. It happened and that's the truth. But in the modern day, can anyone prove that specific individual dinosaur broke its ankle (or even existed)? Assuming the dinosaur did not leave a fossil, it's probably impossible for anyone to ever back that up with solid evidence.
Or for a modern example, suppose that someone is alone and writes down the number 89509 on a sheet of paper, and then burns the paper, and then later they die without having told anyone the number or written it down anywhere else. Again, it's probably impossible for anyone to ever prove what number was written, unless they have a time machine. But there is a truth of the matter; 89509 was written.

I think this is a helpful set of examples. The only thing I would say is that while I think this is the best way of thinking about truth, it is only one of the various theories. Obviously the major counter theory to this is that things are only true if they are observably true.

@CCarter That's not a different theory. That's a different definition of the word "truth".

I think, therefore I am, well something that thinks.

Hello I found your answer to be the most easy to understand and the most sensible counterargument in my opinion. I have a question though, the way you described your counterargument was that of which if a tree fell and nobody was around to hear it or see it then how do we know it fell. Well then as Neil Degrasse Tyson said "How do you know it fell?"

@Ray - that's true but that's sort of the point as summed up in the quote from Neil Degrasse Tyson in the reply from Aditya above. The question is asking about the definition of truth, this answer gives a useful example of one of the definitions. However, I guess the whole point, is that there are multiple philosophies or theories of truth leading to different definitions.

@CCarter Yes, but it's important to distinguish the case where we have a thing in the world called truth and we want to explain it from the case where we have two things in the world and disagree on which is the more interesting (and thus more worthy of the name "truth"). In the former case, we're both trying to get at some objective, umm, truth, whereas in the latter, we're trying to agree on a useful convention. Because we want to avoid the third case: where both of us are trying to explain a thing, but we're trying to explain two different things, and yet are using the same word for each.

One distinguishes the following two questions:

How is truth defined?
To be true or to be false is a property of
propositions: “Today it rains”. While questions or wishes are no
propositions, and it does not make sense to ask whether they are
true.
Definition: A proposition is true if its content is a fact,
e.g. the claimed event happens: When it rains, then the proposition
“It rains” is true.  Hence there is a correspondence between truth
(being true) on one hand and reality (being real or to happen) on the other hand.

How does one determine whether a proposition is true?
The method to
verify a truth claim, i.e. to verify whether a proposition is true or
false, depends on the domain of investigation.
If it is mathematical
proposition one strives to prove the proposition or to find a counter
example.  If it’s a proposition from physics, the method is
observation or experiment.  In philosophy the method is to provide
arguments (solid reasoning).
But for general statements in science
there is no proof - only hypotheses which have not been refuted until
now. To improve scientific statements or to refute hypotheses is
a method of scientific progress, at least according to the
philosopher Karl Popper, "Conjecture and refutation".

I do not agree with the alternatives  “everything is true until
proven false, or that nothing is true; it's just that is hasn't been
proven false yet”
The question how to find and to verify true statements is the
subject of epistemology.



That "which can be backed up by evidence and which has a solid reasoning connecting the evidence to the idea", that's more commonly referred to as knowledge, roughly speaking (although knowledge is typically defined as "justified true belief" - a belief that is both justified and also true).
Some things can be true, whether any given person (or humanity as a whole) has good reason to believe it to be true or not. 1000 years ago, people might not have had the knowledge that stuff is made of atoms, but it was still true that stuff is made of atoms. Now we do have that knowledge, and it's still true.
Thinking of truth as "that which is in accordance with reality" is reasonable and common.
Although people have said a lot more about that and about what truth is. See the SEP article about truth, for example.

As others mentioned, what you're referring to could also be thought of as a pragmatic definition of truth. In this sense, we might say it's not that having justified belief in something makes that thing a fact in objective reality. But rather, justified beliefs is how we determine what the facts in objective reality are. So if we want to speak about what's "true", we're limited to speaking about justified beliefs, so there's some practical use in defining truth in terms of justified beliefs.
In common discourse, I roughly agree with this. But many people hold beliefs that contradict with what other people believe, with each feeling that their own beliefs are justified, and many consider changing one's beliefs to be a bad thing (despite humanity's knowledge increasing over time, which has resulted in some significant changes in what beliefs are justified). So I think it's important to separate the concept of truth from belief (justified or not), to emphasise that our beliefs may or may not be true, even if we think they're justified. We need to work to figure out what is actually true and how we can know that, and there's always some possibility that we're wrong.

Truth
SEP article on Truth outlines a bunch of theories:
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/truth/
To my knowledge, in modern mathematics, truth is elemental and undefined. There exists a set with two elements designated true, not-true (false). I map this to two items of recognition that arise in my otherwise empty field of awareness A = {T,F}. When I evaluate some statement or proposition P as true or false I somehow map elements from set {T,F} to a new relation A = (P,T) or A = (P,F). In reality the set A = {T,F,NULL} is more robust since some propositions are statements that are both not true and not false. Another set is self and not-self {S,N}. Maybe not-self (nature, unconscious cognition) maps the relation instead of self. When I was young I could score high on any multiple choice examination given by the teachers. But it was more like not-self absorbed the knowledge and provided the answer approved of by the teachers.


why can't the truth be described as something with an idea that can be backed up by solid evidence and reasoning

This doesn't work in the realm of mathematical logic.
There are theories which look true, and all evidence seems to support them being true, but later an unlikely counter example is found. Skewe's number is a common example. This mathoverflow post has more related examples.
If you ignore evidence of things that seem true, and only stick to what can be proven, this discounts many true statements. Gödel's first incompleteness theorem shows there are many statements that are true which are unprovable.
